# How can I fix Quasar vuelidate eror-message type error

Tags: vue.js, validation, quasar, vuelidate

I'm using a "vuelidate" for validation of the Quasar framework.

When I wrote the code below there occurred type error.

(property) error-message: string | Ref
Type 'string | Ref' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

I think "error-message" property is undefined before there occurred an error.

But error-message type were only defined as String type by Quasar team.

How can I fix it? Please help me.

Sorry my bad English

```
          <q-input
            label="Name"
            v-model="company.name"
            @blur="v$.name.$touch()"
            no-error-icon
            :error="v$.name.$error"
            :error-message="
              v$.name.$errors.length ? v$.name.$errors[0].$message : ''
            "
          ></q-input>
```

[image]

Comment: try `unref(v$.name.$errors[0].$message)` - [unref()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#unref)

Answer (score 1):

It seems both

```
unref(v$.name.$errors[0].$message)
```

and

```
v$.name.$errors[0].$message.toString()
```

get rid of this error. I'm not sure which is the better solution.